# which reference variable is null - Attempt to read from field 'android.os.Handler android.support.v4.a.m.a' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

I have a stack trace and it is unclear which reference variable is null.

Attempt to read from field 'android.os.Handler android.support.v4.a.m.a' on a null object reference

```
if (Looper.myLooper() != mActivity.mHandler.getLooper()) {
```

*(my opinion is that mActivity is null)*

1. mActivity is null ?
2. mHandler is null ?

---

A more complete stack Trace - but not part of the question..................

```
D/AndroidRuntime( 8354): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime( 8354): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 8354): Process: za.co.nedsecure.nedbankROA.ete, PID: 8354
E/AndroidRuntime( 8354): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.os.Handler android.support.v4.a.m.a' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime( 8354):at android.support.v4.a.s.f(FragmentManager.java:1476)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8354):at android.support.v4.a.s.b(FragmentManager.java:490)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8354):at xyz.......MainActivity.a(MainActivity.java:299)
```

**MainActivity code is:**

```
if (mainActivityWeakReference.get() != null) {
                    mainActivityWeakReference.get().getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
                }
```

**And my fix:(I hope this is it)**

```
if (mainActivityWeakReference.get() != null && !mainActivityWeakReference.get().isFinishing()) {
                    mainActivityWeakReference.get().getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
                }
```

Comment: Looks like the activity is null

Comment: 90% of the question on SO are easily solved by starting your project in debug and finding it out yourself.

Comment: If I could reproduce this problem, it would be so easy to resolve.

Comment: the error says it: `attempt to read from field '...Handler ...a'`, so that's the object that has the handler field, i.e. the activity. (note that the handler field is renamed `a` by proguard. In a non obfuscated version it would say `... from field '...Handler ...mHandler'`)

Answer (score 3):

You must read more of the stack trace for more clues but really the easiest way to find these is to put the expression across multiple lines.

```
if (Looper
  .myLooper() 
  != 
  mActivity
  .mHandler
  .getLooper()) {
```

Please remember to undo this before comitting the source.

Comment: this seems to be a very nice pro tip. Thanks.

The problem though is that this is not my source code but is part of the Android FragmentManger - package android.support.v4.app;

Comment: @Wayne - Perhaps if you post the stack trace we may be able to help more.

Answer (score 3):

A good way to find this is to put a breakpoint somewhere in the code (right on this line makes sense), and then to evaluate the expression.

You can find Evaluate Expression in the Run menu, or you can use the shortcut which is different depending on whether you are using a pc or mac.

Then put in expressions and hit Evaluate.  When you find the one returning null you have found your problem.

So try running all of the possible nulls and you'll eventually find it:

```
mActivity
mActivity.mHandler
```

Comment: This tip about evaluating an expression is incredibly useful. Unfortunately it was only a couple of months ago that I learned about this feature in IDE's. Now debugging is significantly easier by simply previewing problem code and not crashing the whole process.

Comment: perfect.... another pro tip!! This is what I did, I hacked the code to go into
the method that causes the stack trace, and then did the evaluation as you said. I first tried setting mHandler but because it was marked final I could not alter it. Then I tried setting mActivity to null and that produced the exact same stack trace result. My guess then is that one can safely assume it is the mActivity that is null.